# Regex pattern to remove certain prefixes in a word from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to cleanup a set of strings in Excel to extract certain words after removing some prefixes and extra characters. Initially I was trying this with FIND, LEFT, MID, etc. Then, I came across this helpful post and trying my hand at regex.

https://superuser.com/questions/794536/excel-formulas-for-stripping-out-prefix-suffix-around-number

I have used the UDF given there called Remove which takes a regex argument. Now, I am still not able to remove all the items I wanted to remove.

In the attached Excel you can see what I have tried and what the answer I am looking. 
Here are the Prefixes I wanted to remove: 
The numbers in the beginning surrounded by brackets - Ideally I want this in a separate column.
Anyword before a hyphen here there are a number of them 'l-', 'al-'
and then these prefixes below.
 bi
 bil
 fa
 wa
 wal

How do I write a single regex which would remove all the above prefixes?

Here is the UDF I am using:
Function Remove(objCell As Range, strPattern As String)

```
Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
RegEx.Global = True
RegEx.Pattern = strPattern
Remove = RegEx.Replace(objCell.Value, "")
```

End Function

Here is the link to the XLSM file which contains the data I have:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/et9ee727ompj5fl/Regex%20Trials.xlsm?dl=0

and here is a screenshot to show you what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how regex patterns work in VBA, but I assume you'll need the caret symbol to anchor your regex at the beginning of the string, the vertical bar symbol to group expressions and the question mark symbol for optional matches. In perl-compatible regular expressions you can also use (?!\w) to specify that no word character should follow. For example `Regex.Replace(Obj.CellValue, "^(l-|al-|bi|bil|fa|wa|wal)")` or `^(l-|al-|bi|bil|fa|wa|wal)(?!\w)`. Does that help?

Comment: @rubystallion, thanks a lot. it does definitely help. Of all the solutions posted, your solution gave me something concrete to work on. I think that regex patterns work similarly in VBA as in other languages. After playing around a little bit, I found out this pattern matches a lot of my answers - (l-|al-|bi-|bil|fa|wa-|wa). Here, if I have the caret symbol, it does not seem to work. Why? Also in this case, I needed to write another regex first to remove the numbers in brackets using [0-9:()] - is there a way to combine both into a single regex?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regex for this: you can do some splitting of the cell value and testing of the prefixs against a defined array of prefixs:

> Note: the array values are in an order where substrings of other prefixs are later in the list

```
Public Function RemovePrefix(RngSrc As Range) As String
    If RngSrc.Count > 1 Then Exit Function

On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    Dim Prefixs() As String: Prefixs = Split("wal,wa',wa,bil,bi,fa", ",")

    Dim Arr() As String, i As Long, Temp As String

    Arr = Split(RngSrc, "-")
    If UBound(Arr) > 0 Then
        RemovePrefix = Arr(UBound(Arr))
        Exit Function
    End If

    Arr = Split(RngSrc, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Prefixs)
        Temp = Arr(UBound(Arr))
        If InStr(Temp, Prefixs(i)) = 1 Then
            RemovePrefix = Right(Temp, Len(Temp) - Len(Prefixs(i)))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    RemovePrefix = Temp

ExitFunction:
    If Err Then RemovePrefix = "Error"
End Function
```

Comment: I also added wa' as a prefix as this seems to be indicated from the penultimate line of the example data

Comment: Why not use `RegEx`? all you're doing is building your own version of it

Comment: Mostly, because I've not used it much and I find the nomenclature a little off-putting; the code above just allows easy addition or alteration to the prefixs by changing the array values. (I know you can do the same with a regex as well though)

Comment: @Flephal, thanks for coming up with a function to do the same thing. I am not conversant with VBA and I thought that I could quickly master regex syntax - that is why I was going that route.

Comment: @Flephal Can you please explain your code with a bit of comments? I tried to call the function, but it does seem to work - have you tested it? for example, for (1:1:3) l-raḥmāni
, the output is 1:3) l-raḥmāni whereas answer needed is  raḥmāni

Comment: @F Can you please explain your code with a bit of comments? I tried to call the function, but it does seem to work - have you tested it? for example, for (1:1:3) l-raḥmāni
, the output is 1:3) l-raḥmāni whereas answer needed is  raḥmāni

Comment: Slight bug; code updated and should work now. The code takes a value and does a number of tests. First if there is a hyphen present, it returns the segment after the last hyphen (this is where the error was; UBound(arr) > 0 NOT UBound(arr) > 1). If no hyphen is found it splits the word around spaces then tests the last segment after a space and sees if a prefix is present in position 0 (beginning) of the string and if so removes it. Once a hyphen or prefix has been found, the function exits without further testing.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% perfect for words but should get you started

Breakdown of RegEx `(\d+\:)+\d+`

`(\d+\:)` finds any patterns that match the format `x:`

the plus after the bracket then tells it that this is a repeating pattern.
lastly the `\d+` matches the last digit in the string so that the regex will find a pattern that matches `x:x:x`

The next RegEx `(?!l-|al-|a-|wa-|fa-|bi-)[a-z].*` is a lot more complex.
First of all lets look at the `[a-z]`. This tells it to match any character between a and z. We then want to capture the rest of the word so by using `.*` it captures everything from the first match to the end of the string (this includes non a-z characters). However, we don't want it to capture the first part of the string before the hyphen (in most cases) so by using `?!` We use what's called negative look ahead. This looks for anything inside the brackets and ignores those bits. `|` simply means or. so anything inside that bracket will be ignored from the match.
Go to http://regexr.com/ if you want to have a play around is a handy site to learn/test RegEx

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim matches
    Dim c

    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    For Each c In rng
        With c
            .Offset(0, 6) = ExecuteRegEx(.Value2, "(\d+\:)+\d+")
            .Offset(0, 7) = ExecuteRegEx(.Value2, "(?!l-|al-|a-|wa-|fa-|bi-)[a-z].*")
        End With
    Next c

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function ExecuteRegEx(str As String, pattern As String) As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim matches

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = False

        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(str) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(str)
            ExecuteRegEx = matches(0)
        Else
            ExecuteRegEx = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for coming with an answer. But I need some comments to understand the how the regex really works. What are the 2 Regex doing? I tried them both on the examples I had and I did not really get what I wanted. So, I really need some explanation of how each of the above 2 regex are operating on the example I have given.

Comment: I've updated with notes around regex. How is it not working exactly?